# why am i getting this?? <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001C468108DC8>

Tags: python, one-liner

i was trying to convert some part of my code into a one-liner but I am getting something unexpected

```
print(x for x in [2,3,4,5] if x%2==0)
```

can anyone tell why am I getting this - `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001C468108DC8>` instead of 2 and 4??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing a generator object currently but you can easily turn it into a list comprehension and then it will have the behavior you want:

```
print([x for x in [2,3,4,5] if x%2==0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write list comprehension

```
print([x for x in [2,3,4,5] if x%2==0])
```